# Right to left mixed English and Hebrew characters string

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, right-to-left, hebrew

I am using a simple winforms text box to input strings by the user. The text box accepts English and Hebrew letters only. 
I need the English and Hebrew letters to be inputted from right  to left only. 
For instance when I type f and then g and than two Hebrew letters (I will call then 1 and 2 to help those who don't have Hebrew in there browsers) I will get the sentence:
21gf

I was thinking about maintaining an array of chars to work along side the text box but it seems like a real hassle especially when I need to enable delete and backspace functions from everywhere In the text box.

Ideas?

Comment: *it seems like a real hassle* - It is. Not to mention handling pasting text inside the `TextBox`. That's a nightmare just thinking about it. You even need to use a `RichTextBox` in order to make use of the `SelectionStart` index when a backspace is done to determine its position and work accordingly. Maybe I should stop as I'm making your life harder now which is the opposite of what I'm supposed to do.